# How to Deserialize a JSON string on serverside

Tags: c#, json, angular, json-deserialization

In an Angular, mvc project, I am using JSON.stringify to pass a date in string format to server side. On my sever side, I get the string as "\"05/10/2018\"". I tried various ways to convert it to DateTime but wasn't successful. I guess I need to de-serialize string, convert to date to pass it to sql, but cant figure out how? I browsed to find the answer but no success. Also please let me know if I need to install a nuget package.
Here is client side service class:

```
private GetLOBUrl = 'http://localhost:63213/Vto/GetLOB';
getLOBs(action: string = null, data?: VTO): Observable<VTO[]> {
    return this.http.post<VTO[]>(this.GetLOBUrl + `/?ReportDate=${JSON.stringify(action)}`,null)
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
   errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");
}
```

On the server side, I have issues converting the reportDate to string/date type.

```
 public static IEnumerable<DTO.DropDownItem> SelectLOB(string reportDate)
    {
   //reportDate comes in "\"05/10/2018\"" format. Here I need to convert reportDate to string 

        DateTime rDate = DateTime.Parse(reportDate);
        string query = @"SELECT Id, Description 
                      FROM TABLE 
                      WHERE StartDate = @reportDate AND StopDate is NULL";
        IEnumerable<DTO.DropDownItem> items = new List<DTO.DropDownItem>(0);
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("@reportDate", reportDate);
        using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            items = con.Query<DTO.DropDownItem>(query, param: p, commandType: CommandType.Text);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Use DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: Are any errors being thrown?  Please post any you receive from server side code

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact giving same error as with DateTime.Parse -"System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' "

Comment: Try removing the escaped \" from the reportDate string and run it through the DateTime.Parse.  reportDate = reportDate.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do

```
var dt= (DateTime)JToken.Parse("\"05/10/2018\"");
```

Comment: How do you reference JToken

Comment: ok, I had referenced Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization, but that didn't serve the purpose

Comment: @SilverFish `but that didn't serve the purpose` Unclear? What did you try? what did you get?

Comment: I got -The name 'JToken' does not exist in the current context. I have Json.NET.Web under my nuget packages. Probably will need to install that

Comment: @SilverFish `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` Suggest you update to Vs 2017 or Resharper, that will handle usings for you

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the JToken library as stated above for parsing your json, but I was able to remove the quotes before parsing to a date using the code below if that's all you want to do.

```
  string val = "\"05/10/2018\"".Replace("\"","");
  DateTime rDate = DateTime.Parse(val);
```

Comment: This depends on current culture. For ex it returns 5 oct 2018 in my case (where date format is `dd/MM/yyyyy`) :)